# "Unescaping" quoted strings in PHP when querying MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my database which contains text strings such as `Tablet with 7" Screen and 3" stylus`, for example. When I get this data using PHP (through a Laravel Eloquent model, to be more specific), the string will have extra quotes--it will be presented as `"Tablet with 7"" Screen and 3"" stylus"`. This is also how it is outputted in a `var_dump()`.

How can I strip these extraneous quotation marks easily? I looked into `stripslashes()` and `stripcslashes()` but those didn't seem to do the job. Not sure if this is an issue with how MySQL is storing the data, or if there's some sort of function I'm missing that'll make this easier.

Comment: So uhm, why your quotes are doubled?

Comment: Rather investigate where the doubly escaping originated.

Comment: I really have no idea why. Using Sequel Pro or phpMyAdmin shows the strings being stored properly, but when I get them through the Laravel ORM the strings I receive have double quotes—it almost seems as if my string is being stored as the concatenation of smaller strings.

Comment: @Gautam Gupta: "I really have no idea why" --- so you better find it out than apply some weird solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the double-quote from a string

```
$str = "Tablet with 7\" Screen and 3\" stylus";
$str = str_replace("\"", "", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't quite work but it got me on the right path. 
This is what it should be:

`$str = str_replace("\"\"", "\"", $str);`